# MySQL search in multiple columns using PHP and Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, search

I am trying to create an autocomplete box using ajax and php.  It is a textbox.  As user enters keys, on keyup ajax sends data to php and php searches in the tables and gives result back to ajax to show in the list.

For example if i type tru (it should say (trump towers, manhattan, new york) standing for (building name, areaname, city name).  In the tables i am storing building name, and area name as text in tbl_property, but city name as a number in tbl_property which gets its text name from another tbl_city (city id, city name)

So the entry in tbl_property looks like (trump tower, manhattan, 5) 5 gets changed into new york from tbl city (5, new york).

html/php

```
<div class="autocomplete-list1">
    <input type="text" class="addpropertyinput areaname-list-completed" name="buildingorlocation" id="buildingorlocation" placeholder="Building or Location" onkeyup="autofillbuildingorlocation()" maxlength="50" />
    <ul class="areaname-list" id="property_buildingorlocation_list"></ul>
</div>
```

ajax

```
// Suggest Building or Location on Search Form
function autofillbuildingorlocation()
{
    var min_length = 1; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
    var keyword2 = $('#buildingorlocation').val();
    if (keyword2.length >= min_length)
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: '../classes/countrystatecity.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data:
            {
                keyword2: keyword2
            },
            success: function(msg)
            {
                $('#property_buildingorlocation_list').show();
                $('#property_buildingorlocation_list').html(msg);
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $('#property_buildingorlocation_list').hide();
    }
}

// set_item : this function will be executed when we select an item
function set_item2(item2)
{
    // change input value
    $('#buildingorlocation').val(item2);
    // hide proposition list
    $('#property_buildingorlocation_list').hide();
}
```

php to get building name, area name and city name

```
$keyword2 = '%'.$_POST['keyword2'].'%';

        $select5 = $con->prepare("SELECT city_id, city_name FROM tbl_city WHERE city_name LIKE (:keyword2) LIMIT 0, 5");
        $select5->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $select5->bindParam(':keyword2', $keyword2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $select5->execute();
        $data5 = $select5->fetchAll();

        while($data5=$select5->fetch()) {

        $keyword3 = $data5['city_id'];
        }

        $select6 = $con->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT property_buildingname, property_areaname, property_city FROM tbl_property WHERE (property_buildingname LIKE (:keyword2) OR property_areaname LIKE (:keyword2) OR property_city LIKE (:keyword3)) LIMIT 0, 5");
        $select6->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $select6->bindParam(':keyword3', $keyword3, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $select6->bindParam(':keyword2', $keyword2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $select6->execute();
        $data6 = $select6->fetchAll();
        foreach ($data6 as $row6) {
            // put in bold the written text
            $property_city = str_replace($_POST['keyword2'], '<b>'.$_POST['keyword2'].'</b>', $row6['property_buildingname'].", ".$row6['property_areaname'].", ".$data5['city_name']);
            // add new option
            echo '<li onclick="set_item2(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $row6['property_buildingname'].", ".$row6['property_areaname'].", ".$data5['city_name']).'\')">'.$property_city.'</li>';
        }
```

this is not giving the city name...

I have tried below code also not working

```
$select5 = $con->prepare("SELECT p.property_buildingname, p.property_areaname, c.city_name from tbl_property p, tbl_city c WHERE c.city_id = p.property_city and (p.property_buildingname LIKE (:keyword2) or p.property_areaname LIKE (:keyword2) or p.city_name LIKE (:keyword2)");
        $select5->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $select5->bindParam(':keyword2', $keyword2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $select5->execute();
        $data5 = $select5->fetchAll();
        foreach ($data5 as $row5) {
            // put in bold the written text
            $property_city = str_replace($_POST['keyword2'], '<b>'.$_POST['keyword2'].'</b>', $row5['property_buildingname'].", ".$row5['property_areaname'].", ".$row5['city_name']);
            // add new option
            echo '<li onclick="set_item2(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $row5['property_buildingname'].", ".$row5['property_areaname'].", ".$row5['city_name']).'\')">'.$property_city.'</li>';
        }
```

Comment: what trouble are you getting in php code

Comment: If you're looking for ways to improve, you can always use [LEFT JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html) to reduce number query.

Comment: just run the code than see what errors can we get

Comment: aren't you missing the '%' in the LIKE clause?

Comment: why do you have to complicate things like that? can't you simply do a query like select p.building, p.areaname, c.name from property p, city c where c.id = p.cityid and (p.building like %$keyword% or p.areaname like %$keyword% or p.cityname like %$keyword%)

Comment: Try including the table alias when retrieving from the query suggested by Cr1xus, e.g. $row5['p.property_buildingname'] etc.

Comment: @Cr1xus ----$select5 = $con->prepare("SELECT p.property_buildingname, p.property_areaname, c.city_name from tbl_property p, tbl_city c WHERE c.city_id = p.property_city AND (p.property_buildingname LIKE (:keyword2) OR p.property_areaname LIKE (:keyword2) OR c.city_name LIKE (:keyword2))"); ----- this query is getting the result in print_r now just need to get the results from ajax to html - working on it now